# What is the “-o” argument in find command?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, find

I am currently running this command:

```
find . \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -name "*"` on my macos shell.
```

I found the command in a [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282/7561372) for another problem. I do not understand what `-o` argument is for.

I have looked into find’s man page and searched the web but could not find what is the argument for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## That `-o` means “or”.

As explained in the [`find` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> The POSIX standard specifies parentheses '(', ')', negation '!' and the 'and' and 'or' operators ( -a, -o).

So `-o` is “or” and `-a` is and. Simple as that!

And FWIW, this [ExplainShell page](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20.%20%5C%28%20-type%20d%20-name%20.git%20-prune%20%5C%29%20-o%20-type%20f%20-name%20%22*%22) breaks down the whole command (somewhat) clearly.